# Android: Is it possible to handle a click while another finger is already touching the screen?

Tags: java, android, multi-touch

I'm a beginner in Android development and I'm developing an app for little kids. As you know kids tend to hold the screen with one hand (where it touchs the screen already) and click the screen with another hand. Unfortunately, this renders the screen unresponsive to the clicks. My question is, is there a way to make the screen respond to a click even if it is already touched with one finger?

Comment: For what it's worth, I just tested my devices (Nexus 5x, Lenovo TAB2) and they don't seem to have an issue with a finger being on the screen while another clicks.

Comment: Pretty much all touch screens used today can handle up to 10 simultaneously touches on the screen. If an app doesn't recognize additional touches beyond the first one then it is just a flaw with the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There is, by handling in your `onTouchEvent()` the `MotionEvent` `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN`. Imagine you want to show a `Toast` when more than one finger is touching the screen; you could do it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "More than one finger on screen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
```

You can check the [multi-touch Android developer's page](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/gestures/multi.html) for more info on the subject.